# convert int to binary in smalltalk visualworks

Tags: binary, integer, smalltalk, visualworks

I have a weird issue that I cant seem to resolve so hope that converting this to some other form will help:

```
|coder response|
(coder isBitSet: 1)
ifFalse:[self flagSuccess]
ifTrue:[self flagFailure].
```

now the issue is `coder` is a value from 0 to F, when I get a 5 I want it to be treated as 0101, so that it is FALSE from `isBitSet:`. BUT `isBitSet:` treats it as 101, so it's always true... so basically `isBitSet:` isn't working for any binary number thats 4 bits long UNLESS the number is zero...
how can I get my five so that I can check the 4th bit in the number for a 1 or 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the bitAt: method.  This method extracts a bit from an integer and tells you whether it's a 1 or a 0.  It will extract any bit you want and treat bits higher than the size of the integer as 0's.

```
   5 bitAt: 1  ==> 1
   5 bitAt: 2  ==> 0
   5 bitAt: 3  ==> 1
   5 bitAt: 4  ==> 0
   5 bitAt: 5  ==> 0
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You might not be interpreting the bit numbering correctly. The reason why `5 isBitSet: 1` evaluates to `true` is that `1` refers to the lowest bit. Regardless of whether `5` is represented as `101`, `0101` or even `00101` etc., the lowest bit is always `1` and `5 isBitSet: 1` answers with `true`.